# Unable to sendKeys() into input text field

Tags: java, selenium, sendkeys

I intend to automate a simple form fill Junit test on the following website: https://newdesign.millionandup.com

The input textfield i am attempting to send keys to is identified with id=email and i have tried the following two methods:
1.

```
     WebElement passInput = driver3.findElements(By.className("sidebar__item-text")).get(0); // this xPath does the trick  
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(emailLocator));
     passInput.click();
     passInput.sendKeys("emailID");
     Thread.sleep(3000); // only to see the result
```

2. 

```
WebElement em1 = driver3.findElement(emailLocator);
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver3;
    //driver3.findElement(emailLocator).sendKeys(emString);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", em1);
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='prisoner24601@gouvernement.fr';", em1);
    if (em1.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println("email typed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("unable to send keys, element not interactable");
    }
```

To no avail in both cases, the textfield is still not interactable and i am unable to type the data into it.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments i have attempted a third way:

3.

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']"))); 
     System.out.println("email input located");
     element.click();
     System.out.println("email input clicked");
     element.sendKeys(emString);
```

Element is actually located, but, as soon as the methods click() or sendKeys() are called, the execution stops after stating "element not interactable"

Comment: Which version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: Selenium version 4.0

Comment: use xpath of //input[@id='email']  You'll probably want to use a webdriverwait along with findElement()... so something like this: WebElement element  = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='email'])));   element.sendKeys("emailID");

Comment: Thanks for the effort, i just put the negative outcome as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xpath - `//input[@id='email']` is matching 9 elements in the DOM. Its important to find unique locators - [Link to refer](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)

And the pop-up for Register opens on mouse movement. After mouse movement, will be able to view and interact with the pop-up elements.

Used below xpath to send keys to the element `Email Address` and it worked for me.

```
//form[@id='frmLeadModal']//input[@id='email']
```

Try like below once, it might work for you too.

```
driver.get("https://newdesign.millionandup.com/#initial");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveByOffset(100, 100).perform();
        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//form[@id='frmLeadModal']//input[@id='email']"))).sendKeys("example@email.com");
```

Comment: Thank you, i was absolutely pointing at the wrong element, my bad.